# Calculating slope-adjusted surface area from DSM

Tags: python, gdal, dem, area

Is there a (simple) way to calculate the surface area from a regular DSM raster considering the slope/aspect? In my case I've got a DSM (0.5m resolution) with a building, I would like to calculate the area of the roof material.